# In rancher-compose.yml , questions variable use type string default include $ cann't start

Tags: yaml, rancher

I use rancher, when rancher-compose input $, it can't create stack

`- variable: vzdb_rule
   description: "this line will use regular expression in rancher-compose.yml"
   label: "regular expression"
   default: ^$
   required: true
   type: "string"`

Comment: Do you have a complete example of the YAML file? `$` is not a reserved character in YAML, so this might be a bug in rancher or its interpretation of valid YAML.

Comment: Always your post with requested material. Comments are for comments, not for including missing elements (for one because you cannot format comments properly)

Comment: Just noticed you didn't even bother to properly format your orginal post

Comment: sorry about that , this is my first question in stackoverflow, and thank you  for your answer

Comment: No problem. Getting code formatted right is not really difficult ( click the editited link about my name and you see the edit history). If the answer solves your issue, please consider accepting it, if not you can add  a comment (below my answer). Or if you realise your question was ambiguous/unclear you can try to improve your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you will want to use
`$$` to get `$` in the final yaml file. For example, in rancher compose we have labels with `${stack_name}/${service_name}`.. in compose they look like:
`$${stack_name}/$${service_name}`

Comment: thank you very much , i use variable type string  in rancher-compose.yml,and i want to input `regular expression` ,i will try this answer ,you are good man

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `$`, it is not a reserved character in YAML.

Your example is not a correct YAML file, you cannot indent `description` differently from `variable` if they are keys to the same mapping (which they are).

If you align your keys things load fine:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.util import load_yaml_guess_indent

yaml_str = """\
- variable: vzdb_rule
  description: "In line with the rules of the real-time encoding library of regular expressions"
  label: "实时库编码规则1"
  default: ^$
  required: false
  type: "string"
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)

print(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data))
```

gives:

```
- variable: vzdb_rule
  description: In line with the rules of the real-time encoding library of regular expressions
  label: 实时库编码规则1
  default: ^$
  required: false
  type: string
```